# Is there a way I can convert from USB to LVDS UART (~1Mbps)?

Tags: usb, uart, serial, interface, lvds

I'm working on a spacecraft that requires very low noise levels so it was requested that we pursue LVDS UART. So it's using something similar to RS-422 because it's differential, but instead of a signal that is 0-5V, it is a current loop that produces a differential signal that's about 300 mV.

My issue is that for testing purposes we need to be able to talk to that interface from a computer using USB. Normally we would use USB to TTL UART but that won't work for this situation. It would be nice if there was a USB to LVDS UART such that it presented a standard serial interface to the computer but used LVDS to connect to our board for testing.  An FPGA on the board is handling the UART. The connection needs ~1 Mbps.

So far I've been looking for something like a USB-FTDI TTL cable but that would work with LVDS UART. So far I haven't found anything. Maybe someone with more knowledge than  I can help me find a solution.

*Edit* I don't need product recommendations. When I mentioned looking for products I was merely trying to explain what I had been exploring in trying to find a solution. The core of my question is whether or not doing this was possible and if it was, what kind of solutions should I explore.

Comment: Depends on what your connecting the UART to, if its an FPGA then this might be ok. If its a microprocessor, you may not be able to get usb hardware functionality with such a conversion because most microprocessors either have a phy built in or use UPLI for a USB external phy. Another thing you might want to try is just lowering all I/O voltages 1.8, or maybe 1.2V. If your worried about noise proper grounding and shielding work also, its not that difficult to shield RF

Comment: The UART is being handled by an FPGA

Comment: how much data bandwidth do you need?

Comment: We need about 1 Mbps

Comment: Are you looking for 2x simplex or one duplex LVDS? Actually, regardless of this, all you need is LVDS transceiver connected to that USB-to-UART adapter. It is pretty trivial task, but if you are looking for already made cable that makes this shopping question, not suitable for this site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically an UART does not include a PHY, and thus any external PHY can be used for implementing the communication bus.

So feel free to select any suitable PHY for this, there are a lot of PHYs that implement low EMI by using a differential connection or limiting the slew rate. The PHYs include RS485, CAN, in addition to LVDS of course.

Comment: However choose on with highest Z at 1MHz not 0.1or 100 MHz 1GHz

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the USB dongle's TTL signals to LVDS levels using a conversion IC such as this one: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65mlvd200a.pdf

Note: LVDS isn't 'current loop' per se. It works on voltage.

You could also set aside some pins in your FPGA that convert from TTL to LVDS, assuming you follow the voltage standard banking rules. When you're done with development, you'd de-commission those pins.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question if the LVDS line is full-duplex or half-duplex. In the first case simple full-duplex transceiver (like [SN65LVDS179](https://www.ti.com/product/SN65LVDS179)) connected to TX/Rx of the USB-UART adapter is all you need. In the second case you'd need M-LVDS transceiver (something like [SN65MLVD206B](https://www.ti.com/product/SN65MLVD206B)). The DE/!RE lines can be connected to handshake/flow control pins of the USB-UART chip and controlled by the software

Comment: If they're using a TTL UART, it's full-duplex.

Comment: @hacktastical The hardware channel is. Does not mean the communication protocol is also full duplex. If it is, they need 2 LVDS channels to continue be full-duplex. If it is not, they can get by with single channel. That was my question in the comments.

Comment: OP says they're using a plain UART, which implies that they either don't or haven't contemplated using half-duplex. As it is, LVDS applications are overwhelmingly point-to-point.

Comment: It's full duplex

Comment: @DavidAllen In that case, as I said, a simple full-duplex transceiver (driver and receiver connected to two separate LVDS pairs) is a simplest way to do it. All you need is one chip and couple bypass capacitors. Connect that to basic USB-to-UART dongle and you are done. I saw more than a dozen suitable chips from TI, AD, Microchip, Maxim etc. Pretty much any major manufacturer offers several choices.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8131.pdf) differential driver has outstanding balance so the CM emissions are limited only by the imbalance of the cable.

If you had a spec. for short field emissions, which was critical, you could use a Raised Cosine LPF filter on the Tx data with zero ISI.